# Retrieving cached data from existing Crystal Reports file

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, vbscript

Is there any way to retrieve the cached data from a previously refreshed report and say, dump it to a file?  Basically, I'm looking for the dataset that is being used by the report, and hand-dragging each field onto the canvas or even exporting the file doesn't quite get me where I want.

I'm not particular to a specific solution, be it .NET, vbscripting or even within the program itself...  I'm not overly familiar with the Crystal Report object model, nor .NET, but it seems like with a setting like "EnableSaveDataWithReport", there ought to be a straightforward way.

Oh, and I'm on CR 11 Pro

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting in the file menu option to 'save data with report' and if you export that data, you will get the report formatted data (ie certain fields; formula return results, etc) however it will be only in the report object itself.  what are you missing if you export that data?  It seems you should see it all unless you have 'drill-down' and 'supression' enabled on certain areas.